# groupBy-like function such that the binary predicate holds between consecutive elements of each group instead of any two

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, grouping

On Hackage I see that [`groupBy`'s implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#groupBy) is this:

```hs
groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
```

which means that the predicate `eq` holds between *any two elements of each group*. Examples:

```hs
> difference_eq_1 = ((==1).) . flip (-)
> first_isnt_newline = ((/= '\n').) . const
>
> Data.List.groupBy difference_eq_1 ([1..10] ++ [11,13..21])
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11],[13],[15],[17],[19],[21]]
>
> Data.List.groupBy first_isnt_newline "uno\ndue\ntre"
["uno\ndue\ntre"]
```

What if instead I want to group elements such that the predicate holds between *any pair of **consecutive** elements*, so that the above results would be as follows?

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[13],[15],[17],[19],[21]]
["uno\n","due\n","tre"]
```

I wrote it myself, and it looks a bit ugly

```hs
groupBy' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' p = foldr step []
  where step elem [] = [[elem]]
        step elem gs'@((g'@(prev:g)):gs)
          | elem `p` prev = (elem:g'):gs
          | otherwise = [elem]:gs'
```

So I was wandering if such a function exists already and I just don't find it.

As regards the second usage, `Data.List.groupBy first_isnt_newline`, where the binary predicate basically ignores the second argument and applies a unary predicate to the first, I've just found that `Data.List.HT.segmentAfter unary_predicate` does the job, where `unary_predicate` is the negation of the unary predicate in which `const`'s output is forwarded. In other words `Data.List.groupBy ((/= '\n').) . const === Data.List.HT.segmentAfter (=='\n')`.

Comment: "*which means that the preticate eq holds between any two elements of each group*". Strictly speaking *no*, it holds by the *first* of the group and the rest of the group.

Comment: The idea is however that you pass an *equivalence* relation, which is *transitive*, so it means that if `p x y` holds and `p y z` holds, then `p x z` should hold as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`groupBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/groupBy) package that does exactly that.

But here’s another way of implementing it:

- Zip the list with its tail to test the predicate on adjacent elements
- Generate a “group index” by scanning the result and incrementing the group whenever the predicate is false
- Group by the index
- Remove the indices

```
groupByAdjacent :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupByAdjacent p xs
  = fmap (fmap fst)
  $ groupBy ((==) `on` snd)
  $ zip xs
  $ scanl' (\ g (a, b) -> if p a b then g else succ g) 0
  $ zip xs
  $ drop 1 xs
```

For an input like `[1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 20, 30]`, the predicate will return `[True, True, False, True, False, False]` and the resulting group indices will be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3]`.

The scan can also be written pointfree as `scanr (bool succ id . uncurry p) 0`, since the scan direction doesn’t matter (although the group indices will be reversed). The group index might be handy or just more readable to keep as an integer, but it could be a `Bool` instead, because the minimum size of a group is 1: the functional argument of the scan would be `bool not id . uncurry p`, which can be simplified to `(==) . uncurry p`. And several of these parts could be factored into reusable functions, like `zipNext = zip <*> drop 1`, but I’ve inlined them for simplicity’s sake.

Comment: As regards `fmap (fmap fst)`, it's a bit cryptic, and I find `fmap fst <$>` clearer. However, accepted, as the it gives me the useful link at the top and a lot of interesting hints in the last paragraph, thanks!

Comment: @Enrico: I really just wanted to make it fit in with the chain of `($)` applications, which incidentally makes it easier to refactor into `(.)` compositions if you’re so inclined. TMTOWTDI though: `fmap (fmap f) xs` = `fmap f <$> xs` = `(f <$>) <$> xs` = `(fmap . fmap) f xs` = `f <$$> xs` = …. Personally I actually like the idiom of `f . … . f` *n* times where `f` is a “mapping” function of some kind (`fmap`, `traverse`, `foldMap`, `(=<<)`, `(<<=)`, &c.) to illustrate mapping under *n* layers of structure—although typically I’d give them more descriptive names in context.